# Compare 2d numpy array to itself to form 3d array

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a simple 2d numpy array like this

```
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

What I'm trying to do is multiply each row of the array by itself to form a 3d array, (so that `1*1 = 1` and anything else will be `0`, essentailly an `and` function):

```
array([[[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]],
       [[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]],
       ...,
       ...,
       ...])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is pretty simple. If the array is `x`:

```
x[np.newaxis,:,:]*x[:,np.newaxis,:]
```

And this works with things such as logical expressions, if you want to just compare on identical elements in each row, you could do something like:

```
np.logical_not(np.logical_xor(x[np.newaxis,:,:], x[:,np.newaxis,:]))
```

Which would return:

```
array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False]],

       [[ True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True]],

       ...,
       ...,
       ...], dtype=bool)
```